# Передать параметры для вывода yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть модуль admin. С помощью GRUD сгенерировано виды, модели, контроллеры
модель Caregory и модель Content.
В Caregory и таблице category записаны категории и подкатегории товаров -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В Content есть вывод плиткой 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Между собой таблицы связанные по Content.category_id = Category.id
Мне нужно при нажатии на ссылку перейти, чтобы выводило вьюшку с товарами данной категории. 
Насколько я понимаю нужно сделать так, чтобы был запрос где категории сравниваются , что-то типо

```
 $categories = Category::find()
        ->select('id','name')
        ->where('content.category_id = category.id')
        ->all();
```

Но как именно прописать незнаю.
Создал в контроллере екшен, где по урл нужно выводить

```
public function actionAlbum()
    {
        return $this->render('album');
    }
```

Так вот вопрос, как вывести во вьюхе album данные по параметрам категории ??

Comment: Используйте зависимости http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#declaring-relations

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы передать во view параметры сделайте так:

```
public function actionAlbum()
{
     $categories = Category::find()
        ->select('id','name')
        ->where('content.category_id = category.id')
        ->all();

    return $this->render('album', [
         'categories' => $categories
    ]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а как вывести с вью?

Comment: @Vlad Для доступа к переменной во view просто вызовите её, например так: <?=$categories; ?>